# How can I access Closure JavaScript minifier using Perl's LWP::UserAgent?

Tags: perl, http, request, lwp

I'm trying to get Code Closure to work, but unfortunately, there's always an error thrown.

Here's the code:

```
use LWP::UserAgent;
use HTTP::Request::Common;
use HTTP::Response;

my $name = 'test.js';
my $agent = new LWP::UserAgent();
$agent->agent("curl/7.21.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.21.0 OpenSSL/0.9.8o zlib/1.2.3.4 libidn/1.18");

$res = $agent->request(POST 'http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/compile',
           content_type => 'multipart/form-data',
           content      => [
                   output_info => 'compiled_code',
                           compilation_level => 'SIMPLE_OPTIMIZATIONS',
                   output_format => 'text',
                   js_code => [File::Spec->rel2abs($name)]
                       ]);

if ($res->is_success) {
    $minified = $res->decoded_content;
    print $minified;die;
}
```

I get the following error:

> Error(13): No output information to produce, yet compilation was requested.

Here's the api reference I used:
http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/closure/compiler/docs/api-ref.html

Hope anyone knows what's going wrong here. Thanks.

Comment: Why are you faking `user-agent`?

Comment: If you are not averse to using more modules, search for 'Closure' on http://search.cpan.org, this task has been made into a module at least twice already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass as js_code the actual code to compile.   Try (removing the form-data content_type header):

```
use File::Slurp "read_file";
...
     js_code => scalar( read_file($name) ),
```

I see you are trying to use POST's file upload feature; what in the API documentation do you see that makes you think that would work?  If there is something there, I don't see it.

Comment: +1 Absolutely correct. In addition, `multipart/form-data` is incorrect.

Comment: @Sinan Ünür: figured that out too.  You don't need a content type at all; presumably it defaults correctly.

Comment: See HTTP::Request::Common for details of the [$filename] syntax.  Sinan, absolutely correct in what way? Did either of you try using a different filename that didn't exist?  Didn't you get an error message about your file name not being found?

Comment: Nice editing ysth, heh, you didn't see that just now.  Previously this reply claimed that js_code => [$filename] would send the filename not the data.  It does send the data, but in the format of a file upload, not as the google api requires it.

Comment: @MkV Absolutely correct in that `js_code => scalar( read_file($name) ),` is the right way to specify it. `read_file` will croak if the file in `$name` cannot be found. I put the file in the same directory as my example. BTW, the editing function on SO exists for a reason. The edit history is not secret.

Comment: @MkV: yes, I first read the API doc, then looked at your code and misinterpreted it.  But I still don't why you wanted to do a file upload.  BTW, the HTTP::Request::Common doc could use some examples; it says the file upload feature is triggered by giving 'form-data' as the content type, not the typical 'multipart/form-data'.  Do you know if the doc is wrong?

Comment: Thanks! Now it works. In fact, I've used $file->open instead of read_file, because the FileHandle opject is needed, anyway.

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; use warnings;

use File::Slurp;
use LWP::UserAgent;

my $agent = LWP::UserAgent->new;
my $script = 'test.js';

my $response = $agent->post(
    'http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/compile',
    content_type => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    content => [
        compilation_level => 'SIMPLE_OPTIMIZATIONS',
        output_info => 'compiled_code',
        output_format => 'text',
        js_code => scalar read_file($script),
    ],
);

if ($response->is_success) {
    my $minified = $response->decoded_content;
    print $minified;
}
```

Output:

```
C:\Temp> cat test.js
// ADD YOUR CODE HERE
function hello(name) {
  alert('Hello, ' + name);
}
hello('New user');



C:\Temp> t
function hello(a){alert("Hello, "+a)}hello("New user");
```